# What is the definition of "atomic elements" and "standard basis" in a Boolean Formula?

Tags: notation, propositional-calculus, first-order-logic

I recently saw the following formulation in a paper:

> [...] We have variable variables $x_1, \dots, x_m$, assuming natural number values. We consider Boolean Formulae that are formed using the standard basis over atomic elements of the form $(x_i = x_j)$ and $(x_i \neq x_j)$, where the predicate $(x_i = x_j)$ is satisfied if and only if $x_i$ and $x_j$ are assigned the same value. [...] A model for such a formula $F(x_1, \dots, x_m)$ is an assignment of the variables such that $F$ is satisfied.

I tried to read up on the definition of "atomic elements" and "standard basis" in Boolean Formulae, but I could not find anything -- is the formula defined here a propositional logic formula? Or a "first-order" formula, defined over a structure with the domain being the natural numbers? If so, how it can it still be a "Boolean Formula"? Or is the definition given here simply ambiguous?

Comment: Maybe *atomic element* means *atomic formula* or negation of an atomic formula.

Comment: IMO standard basis is not really helpful; it means that we consider the formulas that are boolean combination of atomic and negated atomic.

Comment: So the predicated would be atomic/non-atomic elements and we _do not_ consider the formula to be over a structure? How it can be parameterized by $x_1, \dots, x_m$ then?

Comment: What I mean is that formula $F(x_1,…,x_m)$ will be e.g. $(x_1=x_2) \land \lnot (x_{m-1} = x_m)$

Comment: The structure will be $\mathbb n$: "We have variables assuming natural number values."